# Many to many relationship in Dynamic Data

Tags: c#, sql, dynamic-data

I've just created a Dynamic Data project and I have a lot of many-to-many relationships and elements in my database project. The big problem is that when I want to edit/insert an element, because every many-to-many relationship is "translated" in a list of checkboxes. So, for the entity I want to insert/edit it would result a page of ~4000px height full of many-to-many elements.

Like this ( let's say we have a many-to-many relationship between products and categories ):

```
 Column                             Elements


 Name                              -textbox here
 Description                       -multi-line text area here

                                   NameOfCat1(checkbox) NameOfCat2(checkbox)
                                   NameOfCat3(checkbox) NameOfCat4(checkbox)
 Categories                        NameOfCat5(checkbox) NameOfCat6(checkbox)
                                   NameOfCat7(checkbox) NameOfCat8(checkbox)
                                   NameOfCat9(checkbox) NameOfCat10(checkbox)
```

What I was thinking right now is to make a custom field named "GridviewCheckboxes", with a GridView where I load my entities, with a checkbox in front of their names ( because gridview also have pagination ).

My questions are:

1) It is okay to follow [this tutorial](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/312_Customizing_Fields_in_ASPNet_Dynamic_Data_Website-Part_2.aspx)  ?

2) How can I make that gridview to load my specific many-to-many relantionship ?

Because I have Products-Categories, but I could also have Cars-Garages and I could also have Persons-Cities and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have in my ManyToMany_edit.ascx.cs for the moment.

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Register for the DataSource's updating event
    EntityDataSource ds = (EntityDataSource)this.FindDataSourceControl();

    // This field template is used both for Editing and Inserting
    ds.Updating += new EventHandler<EntityDataSourceChangingEventArgs>(DataSource_UpdatingOrInserting);
    ds.Inserting += new EventHandler<EntityDataSourceChangingEventArgs>(DataSource_UpdatingOrInserting);


}

void DataSource_UpdatingOrInserting(object sender, EntityDataSourceChangingEventArgs e) {
    MetaTable childTable = ChildrenColumn.ChildTable;

    // Comments assume employee/territory for illustration, but the code is generic

    // Get the collection of territories for this employee
    RelatedEnd entityCollection = (RelatedEnd)Column.EntityTypeProperty.GetValue(e.Entity, null);

    // In Edit mode, make sure it's loaded (doesn't make sense in Insert mode)
    if (Mode == DataBoundControlMode.Edit && !entityCollection.IsLoaded) {
        entityCollection.Load();
    }

    // Get an IList from it (i.e. the list of territories for the current employee)
    // REVIEW: we should be using EntityCollection directly, but EF doesn't have a
    // non generic type for it. They will add this in vnext
    IList entityList = ((IListSource)entityCollection).GetList();

    // Go through all the territories (not just those for this employee)
    foreach (object childEntity in childTable.GetQuery(e.Context)) {

        // Check if the employee currently has this territory
        bool isCurrentlyInList = entityList.Contains(childEntity);

        // Find the checkbox for this territory, which gives us the new state
        string pkString = childTable.GetPrimaryKeyString(childEntity);
        ListItem listItem = CheckBoxList1.Items.FindByValue(pkString);
        if (listItem == null)
            continue;

        // If the states differs, make the appropriate add/remove change
        if (listItem.Selected) {
            if (!isCurrentlyInList)
                entityList.Add(childEntity);
        }
        else {
            if (isCurrentlyInList)
                entityList.Remove(childEntity);
        }
    }
}

protected void gvMyGrid_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{




}

protected void CheckBoxList1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    MetaTable childTable = ChildrenColumn.ChildTable;

    // Comments assume employee/territory for illustration, but the code is generic

    IList entityList = null;
    ObjectContext objectContext = null;

    if (Mode == DataBoundControlMode.Edit) {
        object entity;
        ICustomTypeDescriptor rowDescriptor = Row as ICustomTypeDescriptor;
        if (rowDescriptor != null) {
            // Get the real entity from the wrapper
            entity = rowDescriptor.GetPropertyOwner(null);
        } else {
            entity = Row;
        }

        // Get the collection of territories for this employee and make sure it's loaded
        RelatedEnd entityCollection = Column.EntityTypeProperty.GetValue(entity, null) as RelatedEnd;
        if (entityCollection == null) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("The ManyToMany template does not support the collection type of the '{0}' column on the '{1}' table.", Column.Name, Table.Name));
        }
        if (!entityCollection.IsLoaded) {
            entityCollection.Load();
        }

        // Get an IList from it (i.e. the list of territories for the current employee)
        // REVIEW: we should be using EntityCollection directly, but EF doesn't have a
        // non generic type for it. They will add this in vnext
        entityList = ((IListSource)entityCollection).GetList();

        // Get the current ObjectContext
        // REVIEW: this is quite a dirty way of doing this. Look for better alternative
        ObjectQuery objectQuery = (ObjectQuery)entityCollection.GetType().GetMethod(
            "CreateSourceQuery").Invoke(entityCollection, null);
        objectContext = objectQuery.Context;
    }

    // Go through all the territories (not just those for this employee)
    foreach (object childEntity in childTable.GetQuery(objectContext)) {
        MetaTable actualTable = MetaTable.GetTable(childEntity.GetType());
        // Create a checkbox for it
        ListItem listItem = new ListItem(
            actualTable.GetDisplayString(childEntity),
            actualTable.GetPrimaryKeyString(childEntity));

        // Make it selected if the current employee has that territory
        if (Mode == DataBoundControlMode.Edit) {
            listItem.Selected = entityList.Contains(childEntity);
        }

        CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(listItem);
    }
}

public override Control DataControl {
    get {
        return gvMyGrid;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this is very very old, but it really stopped for days, could take a look why my ManyToMany always could not get the field data:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39952062/cant-retrieve-manytomany-field-value-in-asp-net-dynamic-data

Comment: I've used DD only for like 1-2 weeks, back than when I was learning c#, sql server, entity framework and so on. I don't know how to help you, sorry.